# PHPexcel library currency Formating not assign to xlsx file

Tags: phpexcel

Anybody please help me to make currency format in xlsx file vai phpexcel library

I have below mention code but got number format not currency format .

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F'.$i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
```

Comment: Set the format mask as a currency format (e.g. `"$"#,##0.00_-`) rather than a number format then. `'#,##0.00'` is not a currency format

Answer (score 0):

just leaving this just in case somebody ask the same thing

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("* #,##0.00");
```